# Just need to check if this equation correspond to this block diagram

Tags: signal, math, system

[image: 1]

$$y(n)=y(n-1)-ax(n-1)$$
Is this correct? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't look right - there are two delay elements and also y(n-1) gets multiplied by alpha and then goes thru an extra delay. I'd expect to see x(n-1) and y(n-2) terms in the formula.

Try solving for when the output is repositioned at the intersection of the alpha block and the forward delay element - call this output z if you want. Now you will have X(n) being subtracted by z(n-2) and the result multiplied by alpha: -

Z(n) = \$\alpha\$[X(n) - Z(n-2)]

and Y(n) = Z(n-1)

Comment: Were you happy with this answer - if so then please consider formally accepting it.